# Add Asterisk in blank spaces recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

Given a string, compute recursively a new string where all the adjacent chars are now separated by a "*".

Example:
allStar(" hello there ") → "*hello*there*"

Here is the code I have so far, but I don't think I am on the right path to solving this.

```
   public static String allStar(String word)


    s = "";

   if (word.equals(s))
   {
     return null;
   }


  else if (word.charAt(0) == ' ')
    {
    //Recursion should take place here
       return "*" + allStar(word.substring(1))


       //another recursive call, but I am not sure what to do!

     }
```

Comment: Please format your code to match some form of standard indentation/spacing.  It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: If `word == ""` you should return `""` rather than `null`.

Comment: Also, don't forget brackets `{}` and semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you want to do if the first `char` isn't a space.  You don't want to modify it.  Take the first character in a substring, unmodified, then make the recursive call:

```
else {
    return word.substring(0, 1) + allStar(word.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try something like this; note it is a really good idea to start with your criteria to stop recursing.

```
public static String allStar(String word) {
  // null or the empty string, bail out (e.g. stop recursion).
  if (word == null || word.length() < 1) {
    return word;
  }
  // The first character.
  char c = word.charAt(0);
  if (c == ' ') {
    // replace a ' ' with a '*' and recurse.
    return "*" + allStar(word.substring(1));
  }
  // pass the character through and recurse.
  return c + allStar(word.substring(1));
}

// Demonstrate that it works.
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(allStar(" hello there "));
}
```

Comment: I think the base case is already taken care of (`word.equals("")`)

Comment: @iamnotmaynard That would fail if the input `word` were `null`. I concede that may be the desired behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if this is supposed to be `null`-smart, or if NPE is acceptable in such cases. My point was more that OP had in fact started with the stopping condition.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I appreciate it. And thank you for commenting your code so I can review it and understand my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution to this :)

```
public String allStar(String str) {

  if(str.isEmpty()) return "";

  String sub = ((str.length()==1)?str.substring(0,1):str.substring(0,1) + "*");

  return sub + allStar(str.substring(1));


}
```